# One Media Query wont override original CSS

Tags: css, media-queries, css-specificity

So I have a media Query that works except for one element which does not even show up when I inspect element, I've looked into specificity with no avail...

```
div.results_box_custom{
width:25%;
height:370px;
border: 1px solid black;
float:left;
padding:0px;
text-align:center;
background:#D9D9E8;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

 div.results_box_custom{
 height:200px !important;
 width:50vw !important;
 min-width:50vw !important;
}
 }
```

I have tried putting the media query element as:

```
body div.results_box_custom
```

but it doesn't change anything...

Not sure why it won't change my CSS as all the other media queried elements do change? thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your media query is [working as expected](https://jsfiddle.net/fsd38g6L/). Also, no reason to use `!important`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Code

HTML

```
<div class="main">
<div class="results_box_custom">test</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main >.results_box_custom{
width:25%;
height:370px;
border: 1px solid black;
float:left;
padding:0px;
text-align:center;
background:#D9D9E8;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

.main>.results_box_custom{
 height:200px !important;
 width:50vw !important;
 min-width:50vw !important;
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure:

- do You have media queries placed after the styles You modify? If you have two files (or two inline `<style>` tags), make sure the one with media queries comes later.
- is it really `div`, you are trying to modify?

Styles with the same specificity declared later in source file(s) will win in case of conflict. Media queries do not make specificity higher. That's the reason You declare them after the declaration they are modifying.

---

Could You provide html fragment for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Finally Figured it out. There was a conflict with a WordPress cache plugin. Not sure why, but removing it fixed my issues!

Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

It appears to be working fine in this code snippet. The div background changes to white when the media query is activated. I would check that the div class is correct in your HTML.

```css
div.results_box_custom{
width:25%;
height:370px;
border: 1px solid black;
float:left;
padding:0px;
text-align:center;
background:#D9D9E8;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

 div.results_box_custom{
 height:200px !important;
 width:50vw !important;
 min-width:50vw !important;
 background:#ffffff;
}
 }
```

```html
<div class="results_box_custom">test</div>
```